# copy a Matrix into another by memcpy in C

Tags: c, matrix, memcpy, void-pointers

I want to write a function to copy a two matrices into one matrix by use of memcpy. It is like C = [A; B] in Matlab. Because, I want to use this function for all the type of data, which means integer and float matrices, I used void pointer.

the code is:

```
void Repmatrix(void *M3, void *M1, int R1, int C1, void *M2, int R2, int C2, size_t t)
{
    if (RC == 'R')
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < R1*C1; i++)
        {
            memcpy(M3+i, M1+i, t);

        }
        for (j = 0; j < R1*C1; j++)
        {
            memcpy(M3+i+j, M1+j, t);

        }
    }
}
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

To clarify it the inputs are:

```
M1 = [
1 2
3 4]
M2 = [
5 6
7 8]
```

the output should be:

```
M3 = [
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8]
```

Comment: How are the matrices declared and created/filled?

Comment: And the question is?..

Comment: Actually, this functioned is called in a main file and the matrices is asked from a user. in this case matrices are declared by pointer and malloc. for example:

int *M1 = malloc(4*sizeof(int));

Comment: The question is that the code is not working properly.

Comment: You using void pointer in arithmetic. Even if it compiles (some compilers allow that, e.g. gcc) - it will behave as it would be `unsigned char*` - so, from what i'm able to understand, sizeof is incorrect. You probably should use `memcpy((char*)M3+i*t), ...)` instead of your `M3+i` (the same goes for every other M*)

Comment: Did you ever wonder why [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), which also takes a sequence rooted at a `void*`, requires you pass the *element size* as a parameter? If so, are you *still* wondering it?

Comment: @WhozCraig: The element size is passed as `t`, and it's also used (as length parameter in `memcpy`). Of course, it should also be used in the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some simple index errors, probably because you copy-and-pasted the loops: The second loop should use `M2`, `C2` and `R2`.

Then, as others have pointed out, you cannot do arithmetic to `void *`. Void pointers are just anonymous handles. If you want to do something with them, you should cast them to pointers to a value type. (GCC seems to allow arithmetic on `void *` and treats them as `char *` for that matter; it only warns in `-pedantic` mode.)

Because you don't know the value type in your function, only its size, cast them to `char *`, because `sizeof(char) == 1`. Then you can use your size `t` in pointer arithmetic like so:

```
void Repmatrix(void *M3, 
    void *M1, int R1, int C1, 
    void *M2, int R2, int C2, size_t t)
{
    char *MM1 = M1;
    char *MM2 = M2;
    char *MM3 = M3;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < R1*C1; i++) {
        memcpy(MM3 + i * t, MM1 + i * t, t);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < R2*C2; j++) {
        memcpy(MM3 + (i + j) * t, MM2 + j * t, t);
    }
}
```

You don't actually need the loop, because the memory in the top and bottom halves is contiguous if you store your matrix in a row-major format:

```
void Repmatrix(void *M3,
    void *M1, int R1, int C1,
    void *M2, int R2, int C2, size_t t)
{
    char *top = M3;
    char *btm = top + R1 * C1 * t;

    memcpy(top, M1, R1 * C1 * t);
    memcpy(btm, M2, R2 * C2 * t);
}
```

A more typesafe variant is to stick to `double` as matrix value and use `double *` pointers:

```
void Repmatrix(double *M3,
    double *M1, int R1, int C1,
    double *M2, int R2, int C2)
{
    memcpy(M3, M1, R1 * C1 * sizeof(*M3));
    memcpy(M3 + R1 * C1, M2, R2 * C2 * sizeof(*M3));
}
```

You'll still have to use `sizeof`, because `memcpy` works with void pointers, but you'll catch any occurrences of passing the wrong pointer type to `Repmatrix`.

Comment: Two side notes - first, gcc allows this because its default language is GNU C (`-std=gnu89`, i believe); if manually set `-std=c89` (or c99, c11) - this functionality should be disabled or at least produce warning. Second, using `double` in all cases is a good thing - double's precision is enough to handle _any_ possible `int` value. `float`, however, is not enough.

Comment: @keltar setting that std only disables things which *conflict* with standard. `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` are needed for stricter behaviour.

Comment: I hadn't set an explicit standard when checking this, but setting `-std=c89` or `-std=c99` will still compile the void-pointer arithmetic without complaint if pedantic mode isn't set. (I had changed the `MM`s back to `M` to check the warnings but didn't undo it before pasting the code - thanks for fixing that.)